# Intento de insertar datos tipo datetime en table con el formato de fecha yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Tags: sql

Mi caso es el siguiente, yo estoy tratando de insertar esta consulta en sql server con el formato de fecha en yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss en la siguiente consulta:

```
  INSERT INTO BCS_EXPEDIENTES_REGISTRADOS (FOLIO, DOCUMENTO, FECHA_REGISTRO_DPS, CANT_PAGINAS) 
VALUES ('24', 'Suc4437_X722INSURGEN_20200305033042.tiff', '2020-04-13 14:13:54', '79')
```

Teniendo el siguiente error:
La conversión del tipo de datos varchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo

El proceso es:
Tengo un valor inicial: 04/13/2020 09:13:41
luego convierto el valor en este formato: =format([G_RECEPCION], "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")a 
2020-04-13 14:13:54
Luego ejecuto el insert y el campo FECHA_REGISTRO_DPS es de tipo datetime y me genera el error.

Alguna idea? necesito insertar El dato tipo datetime en este formato en SQL Server yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el formato `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` depende de las configuraciones de lenguaje y formato de fecha. Lo ideal es que las fechas siempre se manejen en tipos de dato temporales, pero si es necesario pasarlas a cadenas, existen 2 formatos que no dependen de las configuraciones de la conexion: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` y `YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss`. El primero lleva una T en lugar del espacio, y el segundo no lleva guiones. El segundo es el único que se puede usar sin la parte del tiempo.